# Deleting and creating the Domain Group “Everyone” in Sharepoint 2013 using Powershell CSOM

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, csom

With Powershell CSOM and SharePoint 2013, I am trying to reset the permission to the domain group "`Everyone`", with the name "`c:0(.s|true`". Therefore I want to delete and recreate it, so that all the permissions "`Everyone`" has gotten over time have been reset.

What is the correct Powershell CSOM code for executing these actions?

I also want to do the same for the group "`Everyone except external users`", but I suspect it's the same procedure as to the question above.

EDIT: I'm also satisfied with a way to iterate through the permissions and removing them one by one. What is the Powershell CSOM command for removing a groups permission to a list?

Comment: You cannot delete the Everyone group, its a special group. If you did you'd never get it back and trash your whole AD in the process.

Comment: I am aware that it can't be deleted entirely, but I'm pretty sure it can be deleted in the form of hidden, and then recreated (not hidden anymore) with default values (thus default permissions). Am I wrong?

Comment: Yup and I'm not clear why you even want to. The Everyone group is a special AD group the represents all authenticated and unauthenticated users. It can't be changed from that role.

Comment: I am eager to reset its permissions. The default permissions are not what I want the group to have, so my goal is to delete all permissions and set my own custom permissions levels to the group.